# Select values based on other value within joined tables SQL

Tags: mysql, select, join, key-value

I would like to ask for help for an SQL request that give me values from two tables.

As an example I have one Table orders und one table processing.

I would like to make an report of the orders and the state of processing.

```
table orders

id | status   | div
-------------------
1  | wating_r | div1
2  | closed   | div2
3  | closed   | div3
```

-

```
table processing:

id | order_id | type           | date
----------------------------------------
1  |   2      | send_request   | 15.01.15
2  |   2      | send_invoice   | 30.01.15
3  |   1      | send_request   | 01.02.15
4  |   3      | send_request2  | 10.02.15
5  |   3      | send_invoice   | 15.02.15
```

what I would like to get:

```
order_id | status    | date_request  | date_request2 | date_invoice
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | waiting_r |  01.02.15     | NULL          | NULL
2        | closed    |  15.01.15     | NULL          | 30.01.15
3        | closed    | NULL          | 10.02.15      | 15.02.15
```

my solution:

`select orders.id as order_id, orders.status, IF(processing.type='send_invoice',date_format(processing.date, '%Y-%m-%d'), NULL) as date_invoice, IF(processing.type='send_request',date_format(processing.date, '%Y-%m-%d'), NULL) as date_request, IF(processing.type='send_request2',date_format(processing.date, '%Y-%m-%d'), NULL) as date_request2`

`from orders
inner join processing on orders.id = processing.order_id`

`where 
case 
    when orders.status='closed' then processing.type='send_invoice'
    when orders.status='waiting_r' then processing.type='send_request'
    when orders.status='waiting_2'then processing.type='send_request2'
end`

This works fine but with this IF statements I doesn't become the dates from the requests when an invoice was sent - I only get the date of the invoice.

Instead of the case request I tried the following but in this case I have more than one line for every order. When I tried to "group by" I have mixed data.

`where
processing.type in ('send_invoice', 'send_request', 'completion_request_send')`

Comment: Did you try nesting? (ie. **SELECT div FROM orders WHERE id IN (SELECT order_id FROM processing WHERE type = 'send_request')**) and then joining the results?

Comment: not testet yet, thank ya

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to left-join the second table to the first three times, like so.

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.status, 
       p1.date AS date_request,
       p2.date AS date_request2,
       p3.date AS date_invoice
  FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN processing p1 ON o.id = p1.order_id  AND p1.type='send_request'         
  LEFT JOIN processing p2 ON o.id = p2.order_id  AND p2.type='send_request2'
  LEFT JOIN processing p3 ON o.id = p3.order_id  AND p3.type='send_invoice'
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

This left-join with an id-matching criterion and the specific type choice pulls out the rows you need for each column. Left, as opposed to inner, join, allows the missing values to be shown as null.

Here it is, working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b8c74/5/0

This is a typical pattern for joining a key/value table where the (id/key) pairs are unique.

**Edit** Unfortunately it generates duplicate result set rows in situations where there's a duplicate key for a particular value.  To deal with that, it's necessary to deduplicate the key/value table (`processing`) in this case.

This subquery will do that, taking the latest date value.

```
               SELECT type, order_id, MAX(date) AS date
                 FROM processing
                GROUP BY type, order_id
```

Then you have to use that subquery in the main query. This is where it would be good if MySQL had common table expressions. But it doesn't so things get kind of verbose.

```
SELECT o.id AS order_id, o.status, 
       p1.date AS date_request,
       p2.date AS date_request2,
       p3.date AS date_invoice
  FROM orders o
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT type, order_id, MAX(date) AS date
                 FROM processing
                GROUP BY type, order_id
            ) p1 ON o.id = p1.order_id  AND p1.type='send_request'         
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT type, order_id, MAX(date) AS date
                 FROM processing
                GROUP BY type, order_id
            ) p2 ON o.id = p2.order_id  AND p2.type='send_request2'
  LEFT JOIN (
               SELECT type, order_id, MAX(date) AS date
                 FROM processing
                GROUP BY type, order_id
            ) p3 ON o.id = p3.order_id  AND p3.type='send_invoice'
 ORDER BY 1,2
```

Comment: how can I avoid that I get more than one row when I've more than one 'send_request' to the same 'order_id'? How can I chose which date value will be set for 'date_request' then? Thanks a lot!

Comment: thank you very much! With many (other) data it's real slowly. I got it when I isolate the left join requests with an additional 'where'.